# Convert TIMESTAMPL (timestamp long) to TIMESTAMP ends with 60

Tags: abap

I am having an OData Service returning some `DateTime` values. They are saved in a table in the back end as `TIMESTAMPL` (with some other data).

Now there is the value `20160630084459.5000`. With `MOVE-CORRESPONDING` into the `et_entityset`, where it is a `TIMESTAMP`. Because of the rounding, it gets `20160630084460`, Since a the seconds must be between `00` and `59`, this is not a valid value to return.

My main problem is, that my table has extremely much entries, so I need a performant way to fix this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to convert it to what you want.

```
REPORT zzy NO STANDARD PAGE HEADING.

FORM convert_timestamp.
  DATA(l_t1) = CONV timestampl('20160630084459.5000').
  DATA: l_t2 TYPE timestamp.
  l_t2 = l_t1.
  WRITE / : l_t1, l_t2.
  CONVERT TIME STAMP l_t1 TIME ZONE sy-zonlo INTO DATE DATA(l_date) TIME DATA(l_time).
  CONVERT DATE l_date TIME l_time INTO TIME STAMP l_t2 TIME ZONE sy-zonlo.
  WRITE / l_t2.
ENDFORM.

START-OF-SELECTION.
  PERFORM convert_timestamp.
```

Here is the output.

> 20.160.630.084.459,5000000
> 20.160.630.084.460
> 20.160.630.084.459

Comment: @vwegert Hate it, because then my local variables become global. :) Anyway I have already improved it by getting rid of ABAP OO flavour.

Comment: Then omit out the REPORT and START-OF-SELECTION and leave it to the OP to figure out where to put it. :-)

Comment: Nothing wrong with the OO "flavor", it's just that it adds much more overhead to the two-line payload.

Answer (score 0):

You mention floor in your question but that is not what is happening. The value is rounded. If you simple do use `FLOOR` in your assignment from `TIMESTAMPL` to `TIMESTAMP` you will get the answer you want. If you have to use `MOVE-CORRESPONDING`, just do that first and then do a seperate assignment for the timestamp.

However, this means that 0:59.9 will get translated to 0:59 and not 1:00. If that missing second is OK for your application then just use the FLOOR command. If not it becomes more complicated and you will take a performance hit.